# set auto indent on newline between auto closed HTML tag in vim (<div>|</div>)

Tags: html, vim, emmet

I wonder how to set auto indentation on newline between auto closed HTML tag in Vim?

the | sign is the cursor position

**from:**

```
<div>|</div>
```

**Press *Return* key**

**To:**

```
<div>
   |
</div>
```

**But the Sad reality, is:**

```
<div>
|</div>
```

Comment: The similarity is striking!

Comment: Ha! it really is! Swear I haven't seen it before